# Magento 2 : How to add custom meta tag in head

Tags: magento-2.1, meta-tags, head, open-graph

How to add custom meta tag in head tag of *page-layout-2columns-left*

custom meta tag l want to add is

```
<meta property="og:image" itemprop="image" content="url"/>
```

P.S.

I want this url to be dynamic which change on page to page.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by update `page_layout/2columns-left.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
  <head>
    <meta property="og:image" itemprop="image" content="url"/>
  </head>
.......
.......
</layout>
```

Comment: i had updated question again. i wanted this url to be dynamic for page to page

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
head.additional
```

and add a new block with a custom class and custom phtml

```
<referenceBlock name="head.additional">
    <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\CustomHead" name="custom_head" template="Vendor_Module::custom_head.phtml"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: then what will be the content of customhead.php and phtml file

Comment: you will be able to add your meta tags as in the question